# Electrical outlets in my bathrooms don't have power

Tags: bathroom

Four bathrooms in my house three of them the plugs don't work but the lights do the only GFCI in my house is in the kitchen I already tripped that to see if that was why they weren't working did not help.

Comment: How old is your home? Check for a GFCI in your garage. What were the circumstances of the outage?

Comment: Are you familiar with a circuit breaker panel? Called a "service panel", "breaker box", "load center", etc.?  Often found in utility spaces in your home.

Comment: Lighting circuits and heating (ie plug sockets) should be on different breakers/circuits.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to understand your run-on sentence; would you edit in some periods, and some more information?

Comment: @criggie, that's not true a single bathroom can have everything on 1 circuit. But the op did say the lights were working. since the home is not wired to code of even 30 years ago based on only 1 GFCI in the home I would be looking for a tripped breaker.

Comment: @EdBeal Remember SE is global, and OP hasn't said where they are.  Our local codes may differ significantly.

Comment: The OP did use terms like "GFCI" and "Outlet" though which suggest north America. Also he claimed to have 3 "bathrooms" which suggests either a very large house or a very broad use of the term bathroom which I understand to also be an American thing.

Answer (score 1):

Check for tripped breakers in panel and all outside receptacles for tripped GFI's.